# Redraw a line around a point in a canvas

Tags: canvas, rotation, line

I am having some issues. I want to fill the canvas with multiple lines around a specific canvas point. The result should be a circle (yellow sun) at the right-middle corner surrounded with some sun beams. The result should look somewhat like the old Japanese flag for instance. My main problem is to draw a line and copy it multiple times. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said your problem is drawing a line and copy it multiple times
That sound like just a loop drawing lines, it could be an actual for loop or just with a `setInterval` or the combination of both to animate it a bit.

Here are a few ideas:

- On this, we draw lines from the center straight out, just using some trigonometry and some randomness.

  ```js
  const canvas = document.getElementById("c");
  canvas.width = canvas.height = 140;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2)

  let r = 20;
  let bars = 90;
  function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(-100, -100, 200, 200)

    for (var i = 0; i < 360; i += (360 / bars)) {
      var angle = i * ((Math.PI * 2) / bars);
      var x = Math.cos(angle) * r;
      var y = Math.sin(angle) * r;
      var v = Math.random() + 2;

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(x, y);
      ctx.lineTo(x * v, y * v)
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  }

  setInterval(draw, 100)
  ```

  ```html
  <canvas id="c"></canvas>
  ```
- This other one the lines are straight down and we later rotate the canvas

  ```js
  const canvas = document.getElementById("c");
  canvas.width = canvas.height = 140;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2)

  let r = 20;
  var i = 0;

  function draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(r, -60);
    ctx.lineTo(r, 60)
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.rotate(0.6)
    if (i++ > 20) {
      ctx.clearRect(-100, -100, 200, 200)
      i = 0
    }
  }

  setInterval(draw, 200)
  ```

  ```html
  <canvas id="c"></canvas>
  ```